# Formal alternative to the phrase 'Not taken seriously'

Tags: word-choice, phrases, formality, legalese, synonyms

I'm writing a legal essay and the sentence is

> For example, a young person’s reluctance to seek redress, and that youth are often not taken seriously, their words often not repeated in court rooms.

I was thinking about putting *ignored* in its place but it didn't seem to fit. I typed *ignored* and *overlooked* both into online thesauruses but still nothing appropriate.

Comment: Other than this one issue, do you consider the sentence to be grammatical? Because, to me it seems confusing.... for example, should it not be "... their words **are** often not repeated..."? I'm also struggling a bit with the singular "young person" and plural "youth"...

Comment: Also, what is the "that" doing before _youth_?If the whole shebang is reporting of what someone else argues, with the main verb in the preceding sentence, surely there should be a "that" before _a young person_ too?

Comment: @DavidPugh I **think** (but am not sure) that, in this case, "that" means "the fact that".

Comment: @Catija Both you and David Pugh make relevant points. It seems to me that the writer is trying to say that it is their reluctance to seek redress that causes youth not to be taken seriously. In which case the sentence needs changing altogether.

Comment: @Catija, DavidPugh and WS2. Thank you all for your comments and suggestions. I apologise for the ocnfusion - I chopped the sentence a bit to focus on the part I wanted help with. I was meaning 'the fact that' as Catija said but the overall point was that how restorative justice helps to overcome obstacles such as a young person's reluctance or  the way in which youth's (in general) opinions are overlooked. :)

Comment: ... and that youth are often ***discounted*** [as credible witnesses]

Comment: I'm still a little confused as to what you are trying to say. 'Restorative justice', or at least the way that term is used in the UK, means something slightly different.

Comment: You should edit your post and include the entire sentence or add an ellipsis [...], if you feel it's too wordy.

Answer (score 1):

I'd argue that you see "not take seriously" in enough important news sources to think it's not completely informal.

If you want something different, how about:

*not heeded*

[Heed](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/learner/heed):

> to pay careful attention to somebody’s advice or warning

Comment: A lot of what I would call political bullshit writing (over)uses "addressed" in this kind of context. "The needs of the black community in Ferguson are being addressed".

Comment: Yeah, I hear that, too... "needs are not addressed". You should make an answer with that. :)

Answer (score 0):

Following Catija's advice, I nominate **"not being addressed"**.

It is the perfect register for this kind of writing, i.e., social-workerese, aka hot air.

Answer (score 0):

You might say **not given due consideration**.

[Longman's dictionary](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/consideration) suggests the following sample usage:

> After due consideration, I have decided to tender my resignation.

In many contexts "due consideration" would be a formal version of "take seriously"